# Image is not created with Category creation using Bigcommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working on Bigcommerce project to import category. But in Bigcommerce we don't have direct option to import, hence i am using Category API V3 to create category on Bigcommerce.
The category created successfully. The bigcommerce CDN URL for image is created but the image is not displayed on bigcommerce website.

FYI - I am using Bigcommerce API V3

Please find the API call and result of API. Sorry for misalignment.

[Bigcommerce API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMPTG.png)

[Result Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToCLZ.png)

Please find below coding as well.

```
$fields = array("parent_id" => "27","name" => "category3","description" => "test description","image_url" => "https://imageurl/yhst-130038008324021_2510_1762695707");

$fields = json_encode($fields);

$api_url = 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/storehash/v3/catalog/categories';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('X-Auth-Client: client id','X-Auth-Token: auth token','Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json') );        
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password" ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );   
$response = curl_exec($ch);   
$result = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: pls add acctual code to your question and not screenshots of code as people might want to copy your code and try for them self

Comment: Hi tung, thanks for the reply. I have updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an issue on our end. We've raised an internal engineering ticket to address it, and we hope to roll out a fix soon. I'll update you here when the fix rolls out.

Comment: Hi Karen White, Thanks for the reply. Is the issue fixed now?

Comment: @PriyaDinesh The fix hasn't deployed yet, but I'll definitely let you know when there's an update.

Comment: Hi Karen, Is the issue fixed in Bigcommerce? I need to deploy our website in Bigcommerce. Please advise.

Comment: Hi @PriyaDinesh, The fix has begun to deploy, but it will take a little time to hit all stores. You should start to see this working in a day or two.

Comment: Thanks Karen. I will check and let you know. Thanks for your support

Comment: I have tested category image import using v3 api. I can successfully import images. But image size is reduced and looks very small. The image original size is  220x166 and imported image size is 120x91. Shall i know reason of reduce image size during import image?
I can't display this imported image in my website.

Comment: Hi @PriyaDinesh, this is a secondary issue, related to the original issue. Apologies for the impact to your store! A fix began deployment on Friday, but it'll be another day or two before it hits all stores.

Comment: @KarenWhite I'm hijacking this comment thread - I only get 500 errors when posting to the product variant image endpoint.  Is this an ongoing issue?

Comment: @WillardSolutions It looks like image files > 1MB are causing 500 errors when uploaded by form post. I'll create a ticket to address it. `{"image_url":"https://myimage.jpg"}` should also work, despite what the docs say--we'll update the reference to show that "image_url" is also a valid upload option.